# HTML Canvas Makes Everything Bolder On Right Side

Tags: html, canvas

For some strange and sudden reason, my canvas seems to make lines thicker and darker on the right ~1/4-ish. I have tried multiple browsers and different computers and they all have the same rendering issue EXCEPT for Chrome for Android. Here is a screenshot of the test lines that I drew: [image]

And here is the code in case anyone was wondering:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("foreground");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var height = 450;
var width = 600;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);

  for (var i = 1; i < (800 - (0 * 2)) / 35; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(200 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0, 50 + 0 | 0);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.lineTo(200 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0, 50 + 800 - 0 | 0);
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < (800 - (0 * 2)) / 35; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(200 + 0 | 0, 50 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0);
    context.lineWidth = 0.5;
    context.lineTo(200 + 800 - 0 | 0, 50 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0);
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="foreground"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not clearing the canvas properly: you swapped width and height. The requestanimationframe then draws everything again, and only part of the image is cleared. The part that's not, gets 'thicker'.

Comment: Mind posting that so that I can accept that answer? Turns out you were correct! :)

Comment: Thanks! ;-) Strange that it didn't occur on Chrome for android - perhaps the `requestAnimationFrame` didn't work there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not clearing the canvas properly: you swapped width and height. The `requestAnimationFrame` then draws everything again, and since only part of the image is cleared, the part that's not, gets 'thicker'.

The fix:

```
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("foreground");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var height = 450;
var width = 600;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 1; i < (800 - (0 * 2)) / 35; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(200 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0, 50 + 0 | 0);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.lineTo(200 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0, 50 + 800 - 0 | 0);
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < (800 - (0 * 2)) / 35; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(200 + 0 | 0, 50 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0);
    context.lineWidth = 0.5;
    context.lineTo(200 + 800 - 0 | 0, 50 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0);
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="foreground"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `draw` from `requestAnimationFrame`.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("foreground");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var height = 450;
var width = 600;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);

  for (var i = 1; i < (800 - (0 * 2)) / 35; i++) {
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(200 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0, 50 + 0 | 0);
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.lineTo(200 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0, 50 + 800 - 0 | 0);
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < (800 - (0 * 2)) / 35; i++) {
context.beginPath();
context.lineTo(200 + 0 | 0, 50 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0);
context.lineWidth = 0.5;
context.lineTo(200 + 800 - 0 | 0, 50 + (i * 35) + 0 | 0);
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame();
}

draw();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="foreground"></canvas>
</div>
```